# How do I make a new row in a table which retrieves database fields from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, html-table

I have an array which will fetch rows from the database. But what I want to do is to create a new empty row in the table where if `$row['StudentAnswer']` equals `$row['AnswerContent']` then new field (lets say its called `$row['StudentAnswerWeight'])` = `$row['Weight%']` else `$row['StudentAnswerWeight']` = '0'.

OK the table is an output from a query. The array contains fields from the query. Look at this for an example: `$row['Answercontent'] = Leeds`(This is the correct answer for the question.) `$row['StudentAnswer'] = Leeds` (This is what the student has put for the answer.) The `$row['weight%']` is the percentage of the mark for the correct answer. Let's say that the answer for the above example = 5% of the total marks. Now as the above example shows that the student's answer has matched the correct answer it means that in the new field I want `($row['StudentAnswerWeight']` to display the weight% percentage of the answer which is 5%. If the student got the answer wrong by lets say the Student put in their answer 'Manchester'. The studentanswerweight should = 0% as that the answer is wrong. I hope you now understand what I want to achieve.

How can I do this because I can't seem to get it right?

Below is the array and the fields in the table in php code:

```
<table border='1'>
      <tr>
      <th>Session ID</th>
      <th>Question Number</th>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Correct Answer</th>
      <th>StudentAnswer</th>
      <th>Correct Answer Weight</th>
      <th>Student Answer Weight</th>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      </tr>
      <?php

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "
      <tr>
      <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
      <td>{$row['QuestionNo']}</td>
      <td>{$row['QuestionContent']}</td>
      <td>{$row['AnswerContent']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentAnswer']} </td>
      <td>{$row['Weight%']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentAnswerWeight']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentId']}</td>
      </tr>";
        }
      ?>
```

Comment: Learn to **[ask better questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)**. Better yet, hire a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
...
<td>{$row['Weight%']}</td>
<td>{" . $row['StudentAnswer'] == $row['AnswerContent'] ? $row['Weight%'] : "0" . "}</td>
<td>{$row['StudentId']}</td>
...
```

Think that's what you're trying to do, although I'm still a bit confused.  Does that work?

Or perhaps it would be easier if you tried a more drawn out approach.  It takes more syntax but makes the logic a little bit easier to decifer...

```
...
<td>{$row['Weight%']}</td>
<td>{"; 
if ($row['StudentAnswer'] == $row['AnswerContent'])
  echo "$row['Weight%']";
else
  echo "0";
echo "}</td>
<td>{$row['StudentId']}</td>
...
```

Comment: Nope the field is actually called Weight%. There is not typos the table and fields works fine and output data. But I need to add a new field which I will call StudentAnswerWieght in the array only which will input either 0 if studentanswer and answercontent don't match or input the number from the "Weight%" field from the same in row under the StudentAnswerWeight field. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Think I fixed it now.  It's been a little while since I've used PHP but the '.' character is for concatenating strings and code together if I'm not mistaken, right?

Comment: yeah, '.' is for concatenating strings. Although Im still none the wiser what your original question was all about :)

Comment: The answer didn't work sorry. Can't we make a new $row['...'] and used an if statement. If $row['AnswerContent'] = $row['StudentAnswer'] then $row['...'] = $row['Weight%'] else $row['...'] = '0'. I was thinking along those lines but I could not get it to work, I hope you guys can figure it out :)

Comment: Are you trying to insert back into your mysql table?  I was under the impression you just wanted to print it out on the page in that one table cell?